# Shortening a switch case with a smart algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I am searching for a smart algorithm to get (more less) the same result as in the method below.

It does not actually matter which number gets returned. Important is that each combination of low/high has a unique return value and the return values are between 1 and 36.

The idx's are between 0 and 8 (9 values), never below, never higher.

Any Ideas?

```
// idx1 is never = idx2
private long getIdentifier(int idx1, int idx2) {
    int low = (idx1>idx2)?idx2:idx1;
    int high = ((idx1>idx2)?idx1:idx2);
    switch (low) {
        case 0:
            return high;
        case 1:
            switch (high) {
                case 2:
                    return 9;
                case 3:
                    return 10;
                case 4:
                    return 11;
                case 5:
                    return 12;
                case 6:
                    return 13;
                case 7:
                    return 14;
                case 8:
                    return 15;
            }
        case 2:
            switch (high) {
                case 3:
                    return 16;
                case 4:
                    return 17;
                case 5:
                    return 18;
                case 6:
                    return 19;
                case 7:
                    return 20;
                case 8:
                    return 21;
            }
        case 3:
            switch (high) {
                case 4:
                    return 22;
                case 5:
                    return 23;
                case 6:
                    return 24;
                case 7:
                    return 25;
                case 8:
                    return 26;
            }
        case 4:
            switch (high) {
                case 5:
                    return 27;
                case 6:
                    return 28;
                case 7:
                    return 29;
                case 8:
                    return 30;
            }
        case 5:
            switch (high) {
                case 6:
                    return 31;
                case 7:
                    return 32;
                case 8:
                    return 33;
            }
        case 6:
            switch (high) {
                case 7:
                    return 34;
                case 8:
                    return 35;
            }
        case 7:
            return 36;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Each combination can't have a unique return value if there are 81 combinations and only 36 (or even 37, as in your code sample) outputs. You have many combinations that return 0.

Comment: of course, I thought that was clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a switch statement.

```
private long getIdentifier(int idx1, int idx2) {
    int low  = idx1>idx2 ? idx2 : idx1;
    int high = idx1>idx2 ? idx1 : idx2;
    return (15-low)*low/2+high;
}
```

This returns exactly what the original method returns.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was searching for!

Comment: If the number range changes: Replace 15 by (2 * highest possible number) - 1

Answer (score 6):

You can store the returned values in a 2D array.

```
int[] res = new int[9][9];
...
res[3][8] = 26;
...
return res[low][high];
```

You can either initialize the array with individual assignments (such as `res[3][8]=26`) or you can initialize the array in a single line :

```
int[] res = {{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}};
```

You can easily modify the 2D array to contain only the positions you actually use :

```
int[] res = {{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
             {9,10,11,12,13,14,15},
             {16,17,18,19,20,21},
             {22,23,24,25,26},
             {27,28,29,30},
             {31,32,33},
             {34,35},
             {36}};
```

Now you need to test the following condition before accessing the array :

```
if (low < high && low < res.length && (high - low - 1) < res[low].length) {
    return res[low][high-low-1];
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: then I have unused array values. more than 50%. not a solution.

If it would be that easy, I wouldn't have ask.

Comment: @Unicate Why do you care about having unused values? It's a small array.

Comment: @Unicate All the unused array positions can contain 0, since that's your default return value.

Comment: Thats the difficult thing on the task. do not have unused values ;)
it is more than 40*4=160 useless Bytes

Comment: @Unicate OK, edited answer to use a 2D array that only contains the used indices.

Comment: @Unicate: Who cares about ~160 unused bytes.
You shouldn't be caring about 10,000 unused bytes in most circumstances

Comment: exactly, in most cases, not in all. I do care. And isn't the solution of Hans Klünder nicer anyway?

Answer (score 2):

This does what you want:

```
private static long getIdentifier(int idx1, int idx2) {
  int min = min(idx1, idx2);
  int max = max(idx1, idx2);
  return factor(min) + (max - min);
}

private static long factor(int n) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 8; i > 8 - n; i--) {
    sum += i;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

the factor thingy adds 0 if low is 0, 8 if low is 1, 15 if low is 2 etc. It can probably be improved by giving a formula instead of recalculating through a loop.

Example (prints all numbers from 1 to 36 exactly):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j <= 8; j++) {
      System.out.println(getIdentifier(i, j));
    }
  }
}
```